# When you declare an array with an initial size, are its elements initially empty strings?

Tags: c++, arrays, string

For example the elements of a[20], if not yet defined, would first start out as empty strings (i.e. a[0]=="", a[1]=="", a[2]=="",.....a[20]==""). I'm not sure whether this is correct logic or if I'm confusing it with JavaScript.

Comment: They would be if the array was one of `std::strings`. Or other user defined string type with a default constructor that makes it "empty".

Comment: They would be if the array was an `std::vector` as well.

Comment: The poster has a nice smile.

Answer (score 4):

Arrays in C++ hold elements of a given type. Whether a default initialized array contains empty strings depends on the type of elements held by the array.

When an array is default initialized,

```
SomeType arr[42]; // contains 42 SomeType objects
```

it's elements are also default initialized. For built-in types, such as `int`, `double`, `bool`, and pointers, this means **No initialization** is performed. They could hold any value, and it is undefined behaviour to read from them. For user defined types, the default constructor is called. It the type is something that represents a string, and its default constructor creates an object representing an empty string, then yes, a default initialization of such an array could be said to leave it full of empty strings:

```
std::string strings[42]; // contains 42 empty strings
const char* chars[42];   // contains 42 pointers to char pointing to "random" places
```

Now, there is an initialization called *value initialization*, which has the effect of zero-initializing built-in types, and calling the default constructor for user defined types. This allows you to create arrays of zero-initialized built-in objects:

```
int my_ints[42] = {}; // contains 42 zeros
const char* my_chars[42] = {}; // contains 42 null pointers
char chars[42] = {}; // Contains 42 empty strings (since 0 is string termination by convention)
```

Comment: `char chars[42] = {}; // Contains 42 empty strings` that is just confusing the poster and it's a rather useless concept as it could never store 42 non-empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

`char a[20];`
does not initialize a to anything. It's undefined to read from it.

`char a[20] = {};`
initializes the whole array to zero's (null terminators) .. ie: a is an empty string.

`char a[20]; a[0] = '\0';`
sets the first character to the null terminator. More verbose but possibly more efficient way to create an empty string.

`std::string a;`
Creates an empty C++ string that is ready to use.

Comment: Re: "`char a[20];` does not initialize ..." - it depends on where the definition occurs. If it's at file scope, it initializes all the members to 0.